# What does `(...)` mean when defining a macro?

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

I discovered this in the source code for the Unreal Engine 4 and didn't recognize it. The specific instance of it is:

```
#undef UCLASS

#define UCLASS(...) \
ARadialForceActor_EVENTPARM
```

I'm a fairly new programmer and this kind of macro is unfamiliar to me. My guess was that it is defining a macro that will take every overloaded version of the function `UCLASS` (in other words, every instance of a function named `UCLASS`, regardless of the type and number of parameters) and replace it with the variable `ARadialForceActor_EVENTPARM`. Is that correct? If not, does anyone know what it means? I tried writing a code snippet to test this, but it returned `error: "." may not appear in macro parameter list`. I'll include it below, in case I was right about the macro, in which case I would appreciate it if someone could point out where I went wrong in my code:

```
#include <iostream>

#define foo( . . . ) bar

using namespace std;

int foo() {cout <<54321<<endl;}

int main()
{  bar=12345;
   cout<<bar<<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a [variaidic macro](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace). It only works as of C++11.

Comment: Why did you add the spaces?

Comment: @ Retired Ninja - Oh, yeah, that's a typo. I tried both, and either way it produces the same error

Comment: @Jongware this is **not** a duplicate, your linked question asks how to define a variadic macro - while this one asks what `...` means in the context. Just because two questions have a similar answer does **not** mean that they are duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess of the meaning of `#define foo(...) bar` is correct.  Your error is in thinking that `. . .` and `...` are the same; they are not.  `...` must be written with no spaces between the dots.  If I modify your program to read

```
#include <iostream>

#define foo(...) bar

using std::cout;

int foo()
{
   cout << 54321 << '\n';
}

int main()
{
   bar = 12345;
   cout << bar << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

(please take note of other stylistic corrections; future readers of your code will thank you)

then I get error messages consistent with `foo()` having been replaced with `bar` *in the function definition*, as if you had written

```
int bar
{
    cout << 54321 << '\n';
}
```

which is, in fact, what this tells the preprocessor to do.  (The preprocessor, as always, has no understanding of the syntax of the language proper.)

Comment: So I finally figured out the spaces thing just before Zack's comment. Now I understand what Retired Ninja was referring to. Thanks for the many speedy responses everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
#define FOO(...)
```

this means your macro can accept variable number of arguments. See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) for details.